# CakePHP model question, How can i make table relationship for polls and quiz?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Suppose i want to create polls and quiz with a question and with several options as answers.

Do i have to create Poll model for this ?

How can i track the percentage result for every option in polls table ?

Should i make another table with polls answer options ?

What would be the table relationship for polls question and polls answer ?

Is this correct way?

```
create table polls (id integer not null auto_increment primary key, question varchar(300) not null, mark tinyint not null, created datetime, modified datetime);

create table pollsanswers (id integer not null integer auto_increment primary key, poll_id integer not null, answer varchar(500) not null, mark tityint not null, created datetime, modified datetime);


create table quizes (id integer not null auto_increment primary key, question varchar(300) not null, mark tinyint not null, created datetime, modified datetime);

create table quizesanswers (id integer not null integer auto_increment primary key, quiz_id integer not null, answer varchar(500) not null, mark tityint not null, created datetime, modified datetime);
```

If i make a mysql table polls , then can i access and use that table with posts or other controller or must i create polls_controller.php and poll.php model ?

Can i do this without making new model and controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's me, I'd probably have the following tables:

```
create table polls (
  id integer not null auto_increment primary key, 
  created datetime, 
  modified datetime
);

create table quizzes (
  id integer not null auto_increment primary key,
  created datetime,
  modified datetime
);

create table questions (
  id integer not null auto_increment primary key,
  model varchar(255) not null, -- Poll or Quiz, in this scenario
  foreign_key integer not null,
  question varchar(255) not null,
  created datetime,
  modified datetime
);

create table answers (
  id integer not null auto_increment primary key,
  question_id integer not null,
  answer varchar(255) not null,
  created datetime,
  modified datetime
);
```

My associations would probably be this:

```
Poll hasMany Question
Quiz hasMany Question
Question belongsTo Poll, Quiz
Question hasOne Answer
Answer belongsTo Question
```

Since both polls and quizzes have component questions, I'd try to consolidate that aspect. In order to account for both relationships, I'd make `Question` [polymorphic](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/AD7six/2008/03/13/polymorphic-behavior).

Comment: No, questions are different for polls and quizzess. can't i have a column for answer? Why should i create a different table for answer ? And can you post complete create table for all. That will be easier for understanding. Thanks

Comment: What can be columns for polls and quizzes ?

Comment: The questions themselves may be different, but they're still questions, right? This just isolates the questions in their own tables in case there's ever additional metadata related to questions themselves. If you'd rather, you can certainly include answers as a column in the `questions` table.

Comment: Question hasOne Answer is applicable for Quez only not for Poll. Poll has many answers with percentage.

Comment: So a Poll hasMany Question, each of which hasMany Answer?

Comment: So i need total four models, right ? Poll, Quiz, Question, Answer